# jupyter notebook reindex with pandas error

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm having a strange issue. I have a problem with reindexing when i call my script with a jupyter notebook but it work fine when i call it directly using pycharm.

The first time i execute the notebook after i just started jupyter notebook it work but then it never work again. And it give me this error :

```
 ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

I suspect a problem between pandas and jupyter notebook. Because this error never appear when i use pycharm.

Do you have any idea on how i can fix this problem so that i can call my script from a jupyter notebook ?

I'm using the same conda env for both the jupyter notebook and pycharm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fond that Jupiter-notebook does not re-import the modules every time you execute it.
I had a problem with a variable that was not overwrite I changed the constructor of my script to be able to rewrite it and it work fine now.